# Select some json Objects to display Using Typscript Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

please i wanna to ask you about the result of this code , i couldn't understand the behavior of this on TypeScript

i have a json with two objects and when i wanna to display all the json Objects by this code

```
console.log(this.tabMenu)
```

i got this result
[image]

but when i want to select only title of the first object

```
console.log(this.tabMenu[0].title)
```

the result was empty !!!! but i want to display the title : Pizza
[image]

Please if you can help me to understant this ^^:
Regards

Comment: No way you can get this based on what you are showing. Please share your code

Comment: The code is correct, so the problem is in another place. Where you write the console.log instrucction? the data is "hardcoded" or you're using an Observable -in this case the console.log instruction should be into "subscribe" function-?